# ¿Cómo reescribir el nombre del parámetro del Route Model Binding de Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel

Cuando se crea un conjunto de rutas en Laravel 5.2 usando este tipo de instrucciones:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1', 'middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    Route::resource('chat/messages', 'Chat\ChatController');
});
```

El método resource nos creará los siguientes end-points:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo podría re-escribir el parámetro que el Route Model Binding usará en los métodos? e. g., en lugar de:

```
api/v1/chat/messages/{messages}
```

Tener el singular:

```
api/v1/chat/messages/{message}
```

Answer (score 1):

Vaya, pude resolverlo leyendo más a profundidad la documentación de Laravel, resulta que hay un parámetro llamado "**parameters**" (valga la redundancia) que permite re-escribir el nombre de esa variable:

Esta es la documentación oficial al respecto: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#restful-naming-resource-route-parameters

> **Naming Resource Route Parameters**
>
> By default, Route::resource will create the route parameters for your
>   resource routes based on the resource name. You can easily override
>   this on a per resource basis by passing parameters in the options
>   array. The parameters array should be an associative array of resource
>   names and parameter names:
>
> **Nombrado para parámetros en una ruta de tipo "resource"**
>
> Por defecto, el método Route::resource creará los parametros para tus
>   rutas basándose en un nombre de recurso. Esto se puede re-escribir
>   pasando parámetros en el array de opciones de configuración de la
>   ruta. El array de parámetros debe ser un array asociativo con nombres
>   de recursos y sus parámetros

```
Route::resource('user', 'AdminUserController', ['parameters' => [
    'user' => 'admin_user' ]
]);
```

> The example above generates the following URIs for the resource's show
>   route:

```
/user/{admin_user}
```

> Instead of passing an array of parameter names, you may also simply
>   pass the word singular to instruct Laravel to use the default
>   parameter names, but "singularize" them:

```
Route::resource('users.photos', 'PhotoController', [
    'parameters' => 'singular'
]);

// /users/{user}/photos/{photo}
```

> Alternatively, you may set your resource route parameters to be
>   globally singular or set a global mapping for your resource parameter
>   names:

```
Route::singularResourceParameters();

Route::resourceParameters([
    'user' => 'person', 'photo' => 'image'
]);
```

Entonces mi código quedaría finalmente como:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1', 'middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    Route::resource('chat/messages', 'Chat\ChatController', ['parameters' => [
        'messages' => 'message'
    ]]);
});
```

Comment: Sería buena idea traducir al español la mayor parte de los textos que tomaste en inglés de la documentación, o explica todo con tus propias palabras.

Comment: Excelente propuesta, voy a hacerlo. Saludos.